# Using c++ xpcom asynchronously

Tags: c++, firefox, asynchronous, xpcom

I have a firefox extension which has a XPCOM component written in C++. What would be the best way to communicate with this component asynchronously in such a way that component could 'inform' the main application on any changes, not only respond to calls.
The main goal is to have UI that is changing on informations from XPCOM which is communicating with external system. 
Communication has to be asynchronous by requirement, so checking XPCOM every x seconds is not an option.

I want to know how should architecture of such a system look like and what technology should I use (Workers/streaming/...). The solution should work on firefox 3.5 - 4.0.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use the [observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIObserverService) service, if you don't want to roll stuff on your own. This would be a classic publish-subscribe pattern. Your component would use `notifyObservers()` to "publish" notifications, which the frontend code can then `observe` after declaring interest by `addObserver`.

You could instead have your component expose your own set of interfaces and methods to implement your own observer pattern, similar to what `nsIObserver` does (or even reusing `nsIObserver`). E.g. [`nsIPrefBranch`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/libpref/public/nsIPrefBranch.idl#377) does this already: It reuses `nsIObserver` but does not use the global observer server, but instead keeps track of observers itself.

Whatever you use, you should [make sure that you dispatch notifications on the main thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/XPCOM/Making_cross-thread_calls_using_runnables), as otherwise any Javascript front-end code would bail.